# Button click submit ajax form

Tags: ajax, button, submit

http://jsfiddle.net/pdb26p3q/22/

```
$(".verify").click(function () {

    var ID = $(this).attr('id');
    var dataString = 'verify=' + ID;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function () {
            $(".code").show('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

I have tried using my own server and is not working too

I'm not sure what is the problem, sorry Im quite near to jquery

Edited: The `.code`(input) is not showing. Because if submit successfully the input will be shown.

Comment: Weird thing is when I press Run, it works. But if I refresh it wont work. And the code in my server wont work too.

Comment: Please elaborate that what are you trying to do and what is not working. To see how to ask a good question, please visit: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like

```
var dataString = {verify:ID};
```

Comment: Hi Visnu Katpure I tried in jsfiddle and still the same

Comment: The Weird part is there is no console error. Check out the jsfiddle link above

Comment: in jsfiddle no url for ajax and you have't replace your code

Comment: For code sample see voice.simpsy.com/login/test.php

Comment: Anyway I have figured out my way by using Jquery.post instead. Thanks for the reply though

Comment: Could you add some details of why this should work? Code-only answers are not very useful and are subject to deletion.